# Streaming music with corebluetooth

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

How should I set up the central and peripheral using `CoreBluetooth` to allow users to play music from one `iPhone` to another?

Comment: Simple answer - you can't.  BLE won't have the bandwidth to support this kind of transfer.

Comment: What would I use then to accomplish this?

Comment: You would need to use WiFi

Comment: Classic Bluetooth profiles are not available to iOS apps under Core Bluetooth

Comment: Okay, I see that I would have to use the External Accessory Framework. Is this how devices connect to bluetooth enabled speakers?

Comment: If you want to connect to an A2DP speaker you can use the AVFrameworks to select the destination.  It isn't possible for an iOS device to act as an A2DP receiver